# Automatically set UIView vertical size based on device vertical size (including Auto Layout changes)

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, ios-autolayout

I've been googling on this and can't seem to pinpoint an answer to the question that I have.

I'm writing an app and would like the vertical space of a child UIView to maintain the height of the device or rotation of the parent device regardless of orientation and without hardcoding the values ahead of time.

The structure of my layout is:

```
ViewContainer
  UIView
    UIScrollView
      UIView (Content View)
```

Specifically, I would like to have the vertical space of the Content View initially be set to be the native height of the device/orientation that it is currently running on, and when the device rotates, I would like the vertical space to change to the new vertical height. The UIScrollView will be used to pan horizontally only.

I will be using Quartz to draw in the view. Do I set the initial height via `intrinsicContentSize`? If so how do I query the parent view?

I've tried using `self.superview` within the content view but that doesn't work. How do I detect that a change has occurred, and after it occurs, how do I get the new Y resolution and then apply it? Also I do not want to disable Auto Layout if I don't have to.

Here is a visual of what I want if I haven't made it clear:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AAI3VFkKBARPlYPsoURJOwAmIiGielF5p-w

Comment: I would base the size off of `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height` (or width if you're in landscape). Then use the `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape()` macro. There's a few others like it too. Look them up.

Comment: I've tried modifying the Pure AutoLayout code in TN2154, but I can't detect changes (and am not sure this is the right way to attack the problem in the first place). I can force the size via intrinsicContentSize but not sure how to correctly detect the size, or when the rotation occurs. I've been looking at viewWillTransitionToSize but not sure that's the right approach either.

Comment: To get notified of orientation changes you could subscribe to notifications. Not sure if this suits your use case, but here's the snippet `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];` Then just make sure you have a method called `orientationChanged` which accepts an `NSNotification` parameter

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be taking me down the right track. The only issue I have now is forcing intrinsicContentSize to fire off during the orientationChanged call. Any suggestion there? Getting closer to solving this...

Comment: Got it! I stuffed [self invalidateIntrinsicContentSize]; in the orientationChanged method and it's firing the IntrinsicContentSize call now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an app with the same view hierarchy.

What you want is achievable with pure AutoLayout, with the following constraints. Only vertical constraints are included here:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: ["scrollView" : scrollView]))

scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[contentView]|", options: .allZeros, metrics: nil, views: ["contentView" : contentView]))
```

Since the height of contentView is always correct, not sure whether you still want to be notified of orientation changes.

Comment: Fantastic! This worked. I wanted a pure AutoLayout solution and this did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Sorry this was my first question I've asked here so I'm a little noobish on this front. I just have to check the green checkmark right?